# Show that $x+y$ and $x-y$ are both irrational

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $x$ and $y$ are irrational numbers such that $x^2-y^2$ is a nonzero rational, then $x+y$ and $x-y$ must be irrational.

I've made no progress on this problem, so I don't have any work to show. I suppose I can run into a contradiction, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: hint: $(x+y)(x-y) = x^2-y^2$. also think about what happens when you add/subtract $x+y$ and $x-y$ to/from one another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = x+y$ and $b=x-y$. Because $ab = x^2-y^2 \in \mathbb{Q}^*$, then either $a,b$ are both rational, either they are both irrational. But if they were both rational, then $x=(a+b)/2$ would also be rational, which is not true. So they are both irrational.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x-y)(x+y)$ is rational, then $x-y$ and $x+y$ are either both rational, or both irrational. If they're both rational, then their sum is rational. But their sum is $2x,$ which is irrational.